# cannot load such file -- rack/media_type (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I’m having an issue that I’m struggling to fix. I run the project (`rails s`) then I get the error message

> /.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/media_type (LoadError)

I using:

- ruby 2.2.1
- rails 4.2.5
- bundler 1.17.3

```
bundle info rack
* rack (1.6.13)
```

I didn't find any `media_type` gem package in my project
Has anyone experienced this before? I have searched many posts on Stackoverflow but no results.

Comment: `rack/media_type` is part of Rack. It was first added in Rack 2.0. Apparently some part of your app depends on this. However, as Rails 4.2 requires rack ~> 1.6 (i.e. it does not support rack 2.0), you may have to either remove this dependency or update your Rails version. If possible, you should update Rails.

Comment: Have you tried installing `openjpeg` with `brew`